# Loop through an array returned by vafpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I know how to perform a normal foreach loop but I can't seem to work it for an array returned by the vafpress framework. I am using var_dump(vp_metabox('vp_meta_sample_2.binding_group')); which is generating the below mentioned array. How can I loop through all the images!

```
(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(1) "1" ["url"]=> string(10) "234234.com" ["image"]=> string(62) "http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/bottomright.jpg" ["shortcode"]=> string(108) "[shortcode name="1" url="234234.com" image="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/bottomright.jpg"]" } }
```

I am using the following loop to get the values

```
$age=print_r (vp_metabox('vp_meta_sample_2.binding_group'));
                print_r ($age);
foreach($age as $x=>$x_value)
   {
   echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
   echo "<br>";
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement:

```
$age=print_r (vp_metabox('vp_meta_sample_2.binding_group'));
```

from the code above, `$age` will be empty since `print_r`does not return anything.

Proper:

```
    $age= vp_metabox('vp_meta_sample_2.binding_group');
```

Comment: ok i remove the print_r but can you tell me how to loop this output array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(1) "1" ["url"]=> string(10) "234234.com" ["image"]=> string(62) "http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/bottomright.jpg" ["shortcode"]=> string(108) "[shortcode name="1" url="234234.com" image="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/bottomright.jpg"]" } }

Comment: look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, without `print_r()`

```
$age=vp_metabox('vp_meta_sample_2.binding_group');
```

instead of

```
$age=print_r (vp_metabox('vp_meta_sample_2.binding_group'));
```